# Why the file isn't running as executable?

Tags: permissions, live-usb, executable

I'm reading a [tutorial on creating a Windows 7 bootable](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive.html) disk in Ubuntu.

In the tutorial, it lists an older version of `unetbootin to download`.

It then instructs you to right click on the file, then under permissions, allow it to run as an executable. When I do this though, nothing happens at all.

Is this file just a dud, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you download it to an NTFS disk?

Comment: the file is placed on my ext4 system partition

Comment: Try the `chmod` method described in my answer. See if it works or gives you an error message.

Answer (score 0):

The article you linked to recommends downloading unetbootin from the Ubuntu repositories. The [unetbootin download site](http://unetbootin.github.io/linux_download.html) gives the following instructions:

> To install UNetbootin from the Ubuntu PPA, run the commands:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install unetbootin
> ```

You should be able to run the file from your applications menu once install is complete

Comment: incorrect. you did not read the whole article. I suggests downloading a linked older version that supports ntsf.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the file's owner you should be able to make the file executable through the use of your file manager or using `chmod` in a console. I'll show how to do it both ways.

### Using chmod (console)

```
myuser@myhost:~$ ls -l unetbootin-linux-494 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser mygroup 4320172 feb 28 23:48 unetbootin-linux-494

myuser@myhost:~$ chmod u+x ./unetbootin-linux-494 

myuser@myhost:~$ ls -l unetbootin-linux-494 
-rwxrw-r-- 1 myuser mygroup 4320172 feb 28 23:48 unetbootin-linux-494

myuser@myhost:~$ chmod u-x ./unetbootin-linux-494 

myuser@myhost:~$ ls -l unetbootin-linux-494 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser mygroup 4320172 feb 28 23:48 unetbootin-linux-494
```

In this case `u` tells `chmod` it should modify the file owner permissions, hence the u(ser). The `+` operand indicate that the permissions after it should be added, the `-` operand means permission will be removed. The `x` is the flag for the executable permission.

`chmod u+x file.whatever` reads as "for file.whatever, add execution permission to its owner".

For more details on chmod's usage, check its manual. You can view [online version here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/chmod.1.html) or launch it locally with the command `man chmod` or `man --html=firefox chmod` (to view it in browser, requires the groff package).

---

### Using a graphical file manager

I'm using PCManFM, but the steps are very similar with any file manager.

1. Locate your file and open context menu by right clicking it.

   [image: 1 - pcmanfm context menu]
2. Select the execute box.

   [image: 2 - pcmanfm file properties]
3. Assign permission (owner, group, all).

   [image: 3 - change permission with pcmanfm file properties]
4. Apply changes by clicking the OK button.

Comment: Does not work, will not work if the file system is FAT or NTFS

Comment: @nodws OP said " ...the file is placed on my ext4 system partition". I guess the most common use case for a linux user would be to run unetbootin from a Unix file system such as ext4 or xfs, not fat32 or even ntfs. But anyway, the answers here may help you if this is indeed your case: https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/